# Uniform color of various legend box using geom_segment

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am using geom_segment to generate an annotation background for my plot. In specific, I use the following code to plot the legend. The only problem is that I would like to see the colours in the legend boxes, but it is impossible as my geom_segments are really small (no filling is possible with geom_segment aka you need scale_color_manual and you can not use scale_fill_manual, which would solve the problem).

```
xa <- seq(1,20000)
ya <- rep(0, length(xa))
anna <- as.factor(sample(c(1,2), size = length(xa), replace = T))
ggplot() + geom_segment(aes(x = xa, y = ya, xend = xa, yend = ya + 1,
                            col = anna), 
                          size = 0.1) +
scale_color_manual(name = "tit", values = c("#b47b00", "#000000"),
                                    labels = c('bels1', 'bels2'))
```

[image]
I would like to have only uniform colours in the label boxes, the same that are in the values variable.

Comment: What if you change the size of gem_segment line legend?. Add this to your code: `guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes =list(size=5)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `override.aes` in a `guides` layer like so:

```
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

Full code:

```
ggplot() + 
     geom_segment(aes(x = xa, y = ya, xend = xa, yend = ya + 1, col = anna), size = 0.1) +
     scale_color_manual(name = "tit", values = c("#b47b00", "#000000"),
                                    labels = c('bels1', 'bels2'))+
     guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=5)))
```

[image]